# Android notification addAction not launching broadcast

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, broadcastreceiver, action

Creating notification:

> ```
> PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, (int) taskId, intent, 0);
> intent.setAction(Utils.MARK_AS_DONE);
>
> PendingIntent pIntentMarkAsDone = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
>
> NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
>         .setTicker(ticker)
>         .setContentTitle(title)
>         .setContentText(description)
>         .setSmallIcon(getAlarmIcon(type))
>         .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
>         .setContentIntent(pIntent)
>         .addAction(0, context.getString(R.string.mark_as_done), pIntentMarkAsDone);
>
> Notification notification = builder.build();
> NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
> notificationManager.notify((int) taskId, notification);
> ```

I added the adding using a pending intent with getBroadcast.

Receiver:

> ```
> public class NotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
>     @Override
>     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
>         // Log to check
>     }
> }
> ```

This class should "receive" the action. I also add on Manifest

Manifest:

> ```
> <receiver android:name=".NotificationReceiver">
>     <intent-filter>
>         <action android:name="<package_name>.MARK_AS_DONE"/>
>     </intent-filter>
> </receiver>
> ```

Well, onReceive is not receiving. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: Create a fresh `Intent`, rather than reusing the one in `intent`, and get rid of the `<intent-filter>` from the `<receiver>`.

---

Your first line is:

```
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, (int) taskId, intent, 0);
```

This implies that `intent` identifies some activity. If you created this via `new Intent(context, YourActivityClass.class)`, then it has a `ComponentName` set inside of it, identifying your activity.

Then, you call `setAction()` on `intent` and use it with `getBroadcast()`. However, other than setting (or replacing) the action, everything else in `intent` is the same as it was. In particular, the `ComponentName` identifying the activity is still there. So, when the broadcast is sent, Android cannot deliver it, as the component is invalid (an activity cannot directly receive a broadcast), and the action string is ignored (as once a `ComponentName` is set on an `Intent`, things like actions and categories no longer count for routing).

So, I recommend that you create two `Intent` objects, one for the activity, one for the receiver.

Note that you do not need an action string for the receiver. You can use the explicit `Intent` constructor (`new Intent(context, NotificationReceiver.class)`). In fact, having the action string on the receiver is bad for security, as now *any* app can send you that broadcast. So, I recommend removing the `<intent-filter>` and using an explicit `Intent` to create your broadcast `PendingIntent`.

Comment: Solved! Thank you!
The problem was indeed: new Intent(context, NotificationReceiver.class)